# Puppet escaping my variables when creating a windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file, puppet

I'll keep it brief, I'm trying to run the following code to install vmware, the variables are defined and fully functional, however when this is interperated into the batch file, they aren't escaped and show exactly as they're defined in the code (displayed below).

```
$cmd = 'cd "Single Sign On" & start /wait VMware-SSO-Server.exe /S /L1033 /v"/qr CONFIG_TYPE=Setup SETUP_TYPE=Basic SSO_DB_SERVER_TYPE=Bundled MASTER_PASSWORD=${sso_pwd} RSA_DBA_PASSWORD=${sso_pwd} RSA_USER_PASSWORD=${sso_pwd} COMPUTER_FQDN=test"'
```

Answer (score 1):

In a windows bat file to define a variable you have to use `SET` and then to use these variable you have to put them between `%`

You'll better try like this :

```
@echo off
cd "Single Sign On"

start /wait VMware-SSO-Server.exe /S /L1033 /v /qr CONFIG_TYPE=Setup SETUP_TYPE=Basic SSO_DB_SERVER_TYPE=Bundled MASTER_PASSWORD=%${sso_pwd}% RSA_DBA_PASSWORD=%${sso_pwd}% RSA_USER_PASSWORD=%${sso_pwd}% COMPUTER_FQDN=test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the paste is from your manifest, it doesn't work because you are using single quotes. Therefor variables are not expanded during manifest evaluation.

You will need to use

```
$cmd = "cd \"Single Sign On\" & start /wait ..."
```

Be careful to escape all double quotes, but other than that I see no special characters you need to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was panicking a little due to the fact the error check on my puppetmaster failed, whilst the code worked perfectly on Windows.